# Remote vs Gem-based Themes - Github Pages / Jekyll Theme Question

Tags: themes, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I am a bit confused about appropriate use cases of remote themes and what constitutes a remote theme. More specifically, if I created a customization of a gem-based theme (minima) in a repo (eg. myuser/my_customizations) and wanted to use that customization in multiple other repos using `remote_theme: myuser/use1_of_my_customizations` in that repos _config.yml would that be possible?

For Example:

**myuser/my_customizations** (repo containing my customizations of minima)

in here I have custom styles that I changed from minima to match my use case but I didn't fork the minima repo so I don't have everything copied, I just reference the `theme: minima` in my _config.yml

**myuser/use1_of_custom_theme** (repo where I reference the above repo as my theme)

in here I include `remote_theme: myuser/my_customizations` in the _config.yml to try to get my customizations of minima

So I guess I am trying to use a `remote_theme: user/repo` that is referencing another gem-based theme (minima in this case)....is this possible or no? Instead should I just fork the minima repo, add my changes then use that repo as my remote_theme? I didn't want to do that because if minima changed I wanted to get the latest anytime I build by just referencing the theme: minima in my _config.yml....what is the best way to structure what I want to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Negative - you will need to fork the `minima` theme to `myuser/my_minima` in order to use `remote_theme: myuser/my_minima` within your project(s) `myuser/use1` and `myuser/use2`.   All remote theme does is download the theme using git and update Theme variables accordingly, instead of downloading the Gem.